# different way of doing this query

Tags: sql, oracle

Instead of combining CurrentLoan and History, I want current and history to be in its own column showing the number of books check out by the same member in current and history.

The question:

For each member (member ID, last name, and first name) list the number of books the member currently checked out, and the number of books the member checked out in the past. If a member checked out the same book multiple times, it will be counted multiple times. If a member has no book check out it should be counted as 0.

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE Book
    (bookID INT,
    ISBN INT,
    title varchar (60),
    author  varchar (20),
    publish_year INT,
    category varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (bookID));  

CREATE TABLE Member
    (memberID INT,
    lastname varchar (20),
    firstname varchar (20),
    address varchar(20),
    phone_number INT,   
    limit_ INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (memberID));

CREATE TABLE CurrentLoan
    (memberID INT ,
    bookID INT,
    loan_date DATE,
    due_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (memberID, bookID),
    FOREIGN KEY (memberID) REFERENCES Member(memberID),
    FOREIGN KEY (bookID) REFERENCES Book(bookID));

CREATE TABLE History
    (memberID INT,
    bookID INT,
    loan_date DATE,
    return_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (memberID, bookID, loan_date),
    FOREIGN KEY (memberID) REFERENCES Member(memberID),
    FOREIGN KEY (bookID) REFERENCES Book(bookID));

INSERT INTO Book VALUES (10, 7771452369, 'XML and XQuery', 'Author Le', 2017, 'reference');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (11, 8881245525, 'XQuery: The XML Query Language', 'Jack Se', 2017, 'reference');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (12, 9991123546, 'Yellow Bird', 'Jake Red', 2014, 'reference');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (13, 1212121212, 'The Giving Tree', 'Shel Silverstein', 1964, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (14, 2121212121, 'Gone Fishing', 'Shel Silverstein', 1964, 'reference');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (15, 1313131313, 'The Lazy Dog', 'Jake Red', 2016, 'childrens');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (16, 3131313131, 'The Red Bird', 'Jake Red', 2016, 'childrens');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (17, 1414141414, 'The Very Blue Boy', 'Ben Jen', 2006, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (18, 1113312336, 'Harry Potter 1', 'J. K. Rowling', 2000, 'fiction');
Insert INTO Book VALUES (19, 1113331142, 'Harry Potter 1', 'J. K. Rowling', 2000, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (20, 2221257787, 'The Real Harry Potter 2', 'J. K. Rowling', 2009, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (21, 2221254896, 'The Fake Harry Potter 3', 'J. K. Rowling', 2010, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (22, 2221254896, 'The Fake Harry Potter 3', 'J. K. Rowling', 2010, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (23, 2221254896, 'The Fake Harry Potter 4', 'J. K. Rowling', 2012, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (24, 2221254896, 'The Fake Harry Potter 4', 'J. K. Rowling', 2012, 'fiction');

INSERT INTO Member VALUES (001, 'Lee', 'Nancy', 'Brownlea Drive', 1254896325, 10);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (002, 'Le', 'Ray', '10th Street', 1234561256, 2);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (003, 'Kan', 'Charlie', '5th Street', 1234567236, 8);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (004, 'Brown', 'Joe', 'Elm Street', 1234567845, 9);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (005, 'Smith', 'John', '33 East', 1234567890, 3);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (006, 'Khang', 'Nkaujyi', '358 Spencer', 2145345625, 5);

INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (001, 10, '13-SEP-17', '14-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (001, 11, '13-SEP-17', '14-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (001, 18, '13-SEP-17', '14-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (001, 20, '13-SEP-17', '14-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (001, 22, '13-SEP-17', '14-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (002, 11, '14-FEB-17', '12-MAR-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (003, 19, '12-OCT-17', '09-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (004, 18, '12-OCT-17', '09-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (004, 17, '12-OCT-17', '09-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (005, 18, '12-OCT-17', '09-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (005, 20, '12-OCT-17', '09-NOV-17');

INSERT INTO History VALUES (001, 15, '03-JAN-16', '25-MAY-16');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (002, 21, '03-JAN-16', '25-MAY-16');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (002, 18, '03-JAN-16', '25-MAY-16');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (002, 15, '03-JAN-16', '25-MAY-16');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (002, 10, '03-JAN-16', '25-MAY-16');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (003, 23, '12-FEB-16', '05-MAY-16');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (004, 13, '12-JUN-16', '05-AUG-16');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (004, 20, '12-JUN-16', '05-AUG-16');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (004, 21, '12-JUN-16', '05-AUG-16');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (005, 21, '12-JUN-16', '05-AUG-16');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (005, 24, '12-JUN-16', '05-AUG-16');
COMMIT;
```

Query:

```
SELECT Member.memberID, lastname, firstname, COUNT (loans.bookID) as numberofbooks
FROM Member
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
      SELECT
      memberID, bookID FROM CurrentLoan 
      union all
      SELECT
      memberID, bookID FROM History 
    ) loans ON Member.memberID = Loans.memberID
GROUP BY Member.memberID, lastname, firstname
ORDER BY Member.memberID, lastname, firstname;
```

This is what its doing, it is combining the two: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1a5785/1

Comment: Can you just split the JOIN in two and show the results as two different columns? Or is there an extra requirement?

Comment: @ArthurKazykhanov I think i do need to split it but so far no luck.

Comment: It feels like Deja vu!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Member.memberID, lastname, firstname, 
case when min(CurrentLoanGrp.cnt) is null then 0 else min(CurrentLoanGrp.cnt) end as Currentnumberofbooks,
case when min(HistoryGrp.cnt) is null then 0 else min(HistoryGrp.cnt) end as Historynumberofbooks
FROM Member
left outer join (select count(bookID) cnt, memberID from CurrentLoan group by memberID) CurrentLoanGrp on CurrentLoanGrp.memberID = Member.memberID
left outer join (select count(bookID) cnt, memberID from History group by memberID) HistoryGrp on HistoryGrp.memberID = Member.memberID
GROUP BY Member.memberID, lastname, firstname
ORDER BY Member.memberID, lastname, firstname;
```

Comment: Is there another way of writing that query? A simpler way? I'm not exactly sure what case is. Does cnt = count?

Comment: @tubvajlis There sure is more effective way, not sure about simpler ways. `case` only makes sure you get 0 instead of Null for Members not present in either CurrentLoad or History. You can keep it just `min(CurrentLoanGrp.cnt)` instead of `case` and handle Null values in your code. cnt is just an alias for a column that hold records count.

Comment: okay, that make sense. I've never use case before so I didn't know what it was.